# Adding Culture Events in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

Is There Any Way To Add Culture Events and Holidays in Full-Calendar Package As events Or Background Events?

I Have Added Persian Calendar to Full-Calendar as Locale and Its basically Work Well but i dont know how to add Persian Holidays or Cultural Events with built in functions in fullcalendar package

Comment: You can add anything you want via the Event Sources features - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source . You can add data from your own database, from a remote JSON or Icalendar source, from a public Google calendar, etc.